# Autocomplete does not work correctly in WebStorm (TypeScript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, webstorm

The same project is open. My `Icon` component is typed correctly.

Why does VSCode, when displaying values for the `name` field, show only the values available to it, while in WebStorm it offers values from the whole object?

If I specify a wrong value TypeScript complains about the typing - i.e. it works 100%.

- TypeScript v5.3.3
- WebStorm v2023.3.6

[image]

[image]

###### Tried it:

Invalidate Caches

###### Expecting:

Autocomplete should only show allowed values

Comment: On the picture in webstorm there is a typo alertS instead of alert but it doesn't affect the result. It would still show all values in the 'name' field